# Search with keyPressing on Date Picker(element-ui)

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, element-ui

The problem is on a simple input the `@keyup.enter.native` is working but on date-pickers they are not. What can I do to solve this problem?

```
<app-input :md="3" :sm="4" 
    v-model.number="searchParams.bosTicketNo" 
    label="Numar Sesizare" 
    size="small" 
    prop="bosTicketNo" 
    @keyup.enter.native="onSearch"
/>

<app-date :md="3" :sm="4" 
    v-model="searchParams.endingDate" 
    label="Data Sfarsit" 
    prop="endingDate" 
    size="small" 
    @keyup.enter.native="onSearch" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `@change` instead for datePicker

```
@change="onSearch"
```